# Sound freezes when I plugin headphones. It will just work when I open pavucontol ->configuration-> off and then back to analog duplex

Tags: sound, alsa, configuration, headphones, pavucontrol

Sound in Ubuntu 18.04 freezes when I plugin headphones. It will just work when I open pavucontol ->configuration-> off and then back to analog duplex.It is the same other way round. As soon as the headphone work and are plugged out again, the speakers wont work until I change settings in pavucontrol again.

Any idea to fix this? I have reinstalled Alsamixer etc.

Thanks

Comment: Edit: I use Ubuntu 18.04